# What is the best way to make multicast video stream: RTSP or RTMFP?

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, multicast, rtmp, rtsp-client

What is the best way to make multicast video stream: RTSP or RTMFP?

And what is the difference between these two methods: RTSP sends video direct to users over protocols IGM & BGP (PIM) for multicast send, but RTMFP uses server in the middle to retranslate video to users?

Comment: RTMP is TCP based. Not possible to multicast.

Comment: @szatmary  Thank you. I.e. does it mean that we can compare only RTSP and RTMFP to multicast send, because both is UDP-based?

Comment: Correct. UDP can be multicast on a LAN. TCP can not.